# how to access relationships with async sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, async-await, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, asyncpg

```py
import asyncio

from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.future import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import selectinload
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_async_engine(
        "postgresql+asyncpg://user:pass@localhost/db",
        echo=True,
    )


# expire_on_commit=False will prevent attributes from being expired
# after commit.
async_session = sessionmaker(
    engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession
)


Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    data = Column(String)
    create_date = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    bs = relationship("B")

    # required in order to access columns with server defaults
    # or SQL expression defaults, subsequent to a flush, without
    # triggering an expired load
    __mapper_args__ = {"eager_defaults": True}


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(ForeignKey("a.id"))
    data = Column(String)
    
    
       

async with engine.begin() as conn:
    await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
    await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)


async with async_session() as session:
    async with session.begin():
        session.add_all(
            [
                A(bs=[B(), B()], data="a1"),
                A(bs=[B()], data="a2"),
            ]
        )


async with async_session() as session:
    result = await session.execute(select(A).order_by(A.id))
    a1 = result.scalars().first()

    # no issue: 
    print(a1.name, a1.data)

    # throws error:
    print(a1.bs)
```

Trying to access `a1.bs`  gives this error:

```
     59     current = greenlet.getcurrent()
     60     if not isinstance(current, _AsyncIoGreenlet):
---> 61         raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
     62             "greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_() here. "
     63             "Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?"

MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd2s)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import selectinload

async with async_session() as session:
    result = await session.execute(select(A).order_by(A.id)
                                            .options(selectinload(A.bs)))
    a = result.scalars().first()

    print(a.bs)
```

key is using the [`selectinload` method to prevent implicit IO](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#preventing-implicit-io-when-using-asyncsession)

**UPDATE**

There are a few alternatives to `selectinload` like `joinedload`, `lazyload`. I am still trying to understand the differences.

Comment: this even works when trying to deserialize it syncronous with something like pydantic, because the object references are already there so no async call has to be made.

Comment: the same result is achievable if you put lazy='selectin' into relationship definition, like foo = relationship("B", lazy='selectin'). It also works for sqlmodel: foo = Relationship("a", sa_relationship_kwargs={'lazy': 'selectin'})

Answer (score 13):

[muon’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70105356/735926) is correct if you want eager loading (which is better).

But if for some reason you already have loaded your model and *later* want to load a relationship, there is a way starting with SQLAlchemy **2.0.4**:

Using `session.refresh`, you can tell it to load `a1.bs`:

```
await session.refresh(a1, attribute_names=["bs"])
print(a1.bs)  # This works
```

From the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html):

> New in version 2.0.4: Added support for [`AsyncSession.refresh()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncSession.refresh) and the underlying [`Session.refresh()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.refresh) method to force lazy-loaded relationships to load, if they are named explicitly in the `Session.refresh.attribute_names` parameter.

Comment: love this very short and clear

Answer (score 3):

From [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#preventing-implicit-io-when-using-asyncsession), there are 2 keys:

**1. Use selectinload**

```
stmt = select(A).options(selectinload(A.bs))
```

**2. Set expire_on_commit=False when creating async session**

```
# create AsyncSession with expire_on_commit=False
async_session = AsyncSession(engine, expire_on_commit=False)

# sessionmaker version
async_session = sessionmaker(
   engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession
)

async with async_session() as session:
result = await session.execute(select(A).order_by(A.id))

a1 = result.scalars().first()

# commit would normally expire all attributes
await session.commit()

# access attribute subsequent to commit; this is what
# expire_on_commit=False allows
print(a1.data)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an additional way of accessing the relationship attributes in SQLAlchemy v2, for the case where you have already loaded your model and later want to load a relationship.

As the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#asyncio-orm-avoid-lazyloads) says, you can use `AsyncAttrs`: "*when added to a specific class or more generally to the Declarative Base superclass, provides an accessor AsyncAttrs.awaitable_attrs which delivers any attribute as an awaitable*". So you can create a Declarative Base class like this:

```
class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    pass
```

And then use `awaitable_attrs` to access the relationship that must be previously loaded:

```
a1_bs = await a1.awaitable_attrs.bs
print(a1_bs)
```